# Handling [FileInfo()] format

Tags: python, loops, typeerror, fileinfo

I'm using scrcpy module and trying to get info about folder in mobile device.

With command `devices.sync.list(remote)`, where `remote` is serial of phone and `devices` is Client, I will get `FileInfo` format type of respond:

`[FileInfo(mode=16888, size=3452, mtime=datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 24, 14, 28, 8), path='000_230424_14-26-50')]`

How can I handle this output?

I've tried
`for (mode, size, mtime, path) in devices.sync.list(remote):`
but getting the TypeError
`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable FileInfo object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[FileInfo(mode=16888, size=3452, mtime=datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 24, 14, 28, 8), path='000_230424_14-26-50')]` simply means that you have received a list containing one `FileInfo` object.

`for fileinfo in devices.sync.list(remote):` will iterate over this list, giving you each `FileInfo` object assigned to the `fileinfo` variable.

Presumably you can then access its properties as attributes:

```
for fileinfo in devices.sync.list(remote):
    print(fileinfo.mode)
    print(fileinfo.size)
    # etc.
```